# Select all items that match in field 'A' where one of the matching fields contains a separate field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My question in brief is as follows...

Sales order Lines (different items on a sales order)

```
Sales Order Number        Item Number          Category          
1001                      aaa                  Z
1001                      bbb                  X
1001                      ccc                  Y
1002                      bbb                  X
1002                      eee                  W
1003                      ttt                  S
1003                      rrr                  P
1004                      bbb                  X
1005                      eee                  W
```

I would like to show all sales order lines where the sales order contains an item with the category X

so the results may appear something like this;

```
Sales Order Number        Item Number          Category          
1001                      aaa                  Z
1001                      bbb                  X
1001                      ccc                  Y
1002                      bbb                  X
1002                      eee                  W
1004                      bbb                  X
```

as 1003 and 1005 contain no items with category X

Comment: sorry SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

An `Exists` clause should be fine.

```
select * 
from <yourTable> t1
where exists (select null 
              from <yourTable>
              where t1.salesordernumber = salesordernumber
              and category = 'X')
```

Comment: Thanks very much, managed to use your code in my query as follows

Answer (score 0):

Quite an easy one with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders o
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ORDERS o2
    WHERE o.[Sales Order Number] = o2.[Sales Order Number]
    AND o2.Category = 'X'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option without Exists, if you prefer:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE [Sales Order Number] in
     (SELECT DISTINCT [Sales Order Number] from MY_TABLE where [Category] = 'X')
```

I don't tend to like correlated subqueries because I see their performance degrade in some situations more than others, but YMMV.  All the responses so far should work.

Comment: thanks guys, my query turned out to be pretty big because it linked about 6 tables and lots of different joins etc but I used the EXISTS thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    SalesOrders 
WHERE   SalesOrderNumber IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT SalesOrderNumber
         FROM   SalesOrders
         WHERE  Category = 'X')
```